# PHP float number with decimal point rounding

Tags: php, floating-point, number-formatting

I am calculating few numbers (sales_total, service_charge) to get 7% GST. What I get is number with decimal point.

**Example 1:**

```
$sales_total        = 207.50;
$service_charge = 20.75;

$gst                = ($sales + $sc) * .07;
```

Returns me GST =`15.9775`.

**Example 2:**

```
$sales_total        = 28;
$service_charge = 2.8;
$gst                =  ($sales + $sc) * .07;
```

Returns me GST = `2.156`

I need to match the data with a report where the

- Example 1 GST = 16.00  *(my  15.9775)*
- Example 2 GST = 2.15  *(my 2.156)*

I am trying php `round`, `number_format` functions but not getting both of my results correct. `round` gives example 1 result correct, `number_format` gives example 2 correct.

What I am doing wrong, or which function I need to use?

Comment: I'm guessing `($sales + $sc)` should be `($sales + $service_charge)` ?

Comment: According to your examples, PHP is giving you the mathematically correct numbers. Also, your rounding rules seem to differ between each example. I'd be tempted to say, given the information provided that the reports are dodgy...

Comment: @CD001 you are right.. but its not the problem.. its just pseudo code I am sharing..

Comment: To expand on the differing rules. You seem to want example 2 to round _down_ to the nearest 100th, but for example 1, you want it to round _up_ to the nearest whole number.

Comment: @JonStirling provably you are correct. The api I am fetching data from is done in Java.. can that be a convertion difference or they are doing own mechanism to get the difference ?

Comment: @ArifulHaque All I can say is that given the information provided, somebody appears to be doing something screwy, somewhere. And that's as specific as I think we can be. It's unlikely to be simply a difference in programming language use.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks man. I am calling the api provider now.. I've no other option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
round($gst, 2);
```

this will round your variable within 2 decimal houses.

Could you try?

### Edit

Since you want different behaviors in both values I don't think that round can help you in both situations. 
Actually the second example you don't even want a round. You just want to delete the 3rd decimal number so...

In this case I would use the 1st example the round with 2 decimal houses as I said and in the 2nd example I would just delete the 3rd house number or limit in the database>table the float number to 2 decimal houses.

Comment: I tried it.. that makes example 1: `15.98` (expected 16.00) and example 2: `2.16` (expected 2.15)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're probably needing to round with precision decimal places away from zero, so depending on that you could use:

```
$gst = sprintf("%.2f", round($gst, 3 - strlen(round($gst)), PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD));
```

Result:

```
16.00
2.16
```

This shows a precision of 3 decimal places away from zero minus the length of the rounded value. You'll likely need to play around with the rounding mode and precision to get it how you want. The result of `2.15` from `2.156` looks incorrect — it's unclear how you've gotten this value.

> - <sub>**PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP** • Round val up to precision decimal places away from zero, when it is half way there. Making 1.5 into 2
>     and -1.5 into -2.</sub>
> - <sub>**PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN** • Round val down to precision decimal places towards zero, when it is half way there. Making 1.5 into 1 and
>     -1.5 into -1.</sub>
> - <sub>**PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN** • Round val to precision decimal places towards the next even value.</sub>
> - <sub>**PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD** • Round val to precision decimal places towards the next odd value.</sub>

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php